# Displaying multiple error messages in a single message box

Tags: c#, validation, messagebox

I'm currently developing a desktop application with a product maintenance page and im looking for a way to display all validation errors in a single message box.

I am displaying one message box per validation error by using the code below: (validations are bound to a save button)

```
        if ((Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text)) > 20000)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Maximum quantity is 20,000!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            txtQuantity.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if ((Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text)) <= (Convert.ToInt32(txtCriticalLevel.Text)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Quantity is lower than Critical Level.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            txtQuantity.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (txtCriticalLevel.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check for zero values!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            txtCriticalLevel.Focus();
            return;
        }
```

I'd like to give the users the ease of knowing all the errors at once as opposed to knowing them one by one per message box shown.

thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick dirty solution will be :

```
    string errorMessages = String.Empty;

    if ((Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text)) > 20000)
    {
        errorMessages +="- Maximum quantity is 20,000!\r\n";
        txtQuantity.Focus();
        return;
    }

    if ((Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text)) <= (Convert.ToInt32(txtCriticalLevel.Text)))
    {
        errorMessages += "- Quantity is lower than Critical Level.\r\n";
        txtQuantity.Focus();
        return;
    }

    if (txtCriticalLevel.Text == "0")
    {
        errorMessages += "- Please check for zero values!\r\n";
        txtCriticalLevel.Focus();
        return;
    }

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessages))
        MessageBox.Show(errorMessages, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

Comment: when you concat string is better that use StringBuilder https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx

Comment: your code did wonders!!! thank you so much!! but could you explain why its "dirty"?

Comment: Because it needs some refactoring to use 'StringBuilder' rather than String Concatenation like @M.Azad said, and may be some string formating.

Answer (score 2):

you can use StringBuilder and add Errors in it :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


 if ((Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text)) > 20000)
        {
              sb.AppendLine("Maximum quantity is 20,000!");            
        }



if ((Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text)) <= (Convert.ToInt32(txtCriticalLevel.Text)))
    {
       sb.AppendLine("Quantity is lower than Critical Level.");
    }

....
  MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i'll look into this, but how would i factor in the validations? could you show me a sample of possible? :)

Comment: @RonReyes I Update my answer ;)